# uso de cursor para atualização de estoque item a item

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tenho um banco onde o estoque(onhand) deve ser alterado cada vez que um pedido(docentry) for feito, seja ele um pedido confirmado ou não, para isso preciso baixar do estoque a quantidade(qty) do pedido com uma operação simples de subtração(onhand - qty). Minha dúvida é a seguinte, como eu realizo a substituição do estoque de cada item toda vez que um pedido for feito? Consigo fazer isso porém apenas quando especifico o número do pedido mas gostaria de realizar essa operação.
Segue código e imagem do resultado.

[image: imagem]

Basicamente como funcionaria: o Estoque do item está em 3993, após o pedido "15335" o estoque deveria atualizar para 3981 para todos os pedidos onde esse item exista(no caso o 15681 deve mostrar no onhand 3981), depois o cursor deveria atualizar novamente quando chegar no item "AR000001" e diminuir 4 do estoque atualizado 3981. Atualmente o que acontece: o estoque baixa do número 3993 para ambos onde fica 3981 para um e 3989 para outro.

```
--realizando inserção na tabela temporária
insert into #tmpPedidos(Docentry,qty,onhand,conta,itemcode)
(select a.docentry,b.Quantity,c.OnHand,(c.OnHand - b.Quantity),b.ItemCode
from ORDR a 
inner join RDR1 b on a.DocEntry = b.DocEntry
inner join OITW c on b.ItemCode = c.ItemCode
where
a.DocStatus = 'o' and a.CANCELED = 'n' and c.whscode = 
CASE when BPLId = 4 then '301' 
ELSE
'401'
END) --documentos com status abertos não cancelados e com estoque de numero ou 301 ou 401

declare crs cursor
for
select * from #tmpPedidos order by itemcode
update #tmpPedidos set onhand = conta where itemcode = 'ar000001' and Docentry = 15335 --aqui realizo o update indicando um pedido(que funciona)
update #tmpPedidos set conta = onhand - qty where itemcode = 'ar000001' and Docentry = 15335 -- aqui atualizo a conta indicando o pedido(que também funciona)
open crs
fetch next from crs;
```

Agradeço a todos aqueles que puderem ajudar, estou iniciando nessa parte de tabelas temporárias e cursores então não conheço muito sobre o uso dos mesmos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eis solução usando CTE recursiva.

```
-- código #1 v2
with 
Pedidos_seq as (
SELECT *,
       seq= row_number() over (partition by itemcode order by Docentry)
  from #tmpPedidos
),
Le_Pedido as (
SELECT Docentry, qty, onhand, conta, itemcode, seq
  from Pedidos_seq
  where seq = 1
union all
SELECT Ps.Docentry, Ps.qty, LP.conta, (LP.conta - Ps.qty), PS.itemcode, Ps.seq
  from Le_Pedido as LP
       inner join Pedidos_seq as Ps on Ps.itemcode = LP.itemcode
                                      and Ps.seq = (LP.seq +1)
)
SELECT * from Le_Pedido  -- teste
/*
UPDATE P
  set onhand= LP.onhand, conta= LP.conta
  from #tmpPedidos as P
       inner join Le_Pedido as LP on LP.Docentry = P.Docentry
*/
  option (maxrecursion 5000);
```

Não testei; pode conter erro(s).

Se a consulta retornar o que você necessita, então apague a linha que termina com
   -- teste
e retire os comentários da parte final do código.

Comment: Bom dia José! testei aqui e deu um erro no finalzinho "and Ps.seq = (LP.seq +1)" substitui por Ps.seq+1 mas um dos itens sumiu, só aparece 1 ar000001.

Comment: Tinha me esquecido de colocar a coluna seq dentro de Le_Pedido. Já corrigido.

Comment: Agora funcionou perfeitamente como escreveu, sem erros, porém o ar000001 só é mostrado 1x e após isso aparece a mensagem "The statement terminated. The maximum recursion 100 has been exhausted before statement completion"

Comment: @DouglasSouza Qual o número aproximado de linhas da tabela `#tmpPedidos`?

Comment: 4600 linhas nessa tabelinha

Comment: A mensagem de erro indica que o número de recursões atingiu o limite de recursões, cujo valor padrão é 100. Isto somente pode ter ocorrido se para um mesmo valor de `itemcode` existam mais de 100 linhas. Alterei o código #1, definindo o limite de recursões maior.

Answer (score 1):

Amigo, pode fazer o que precisa utilizando uma variável que vai incrementando.
Para isso você precisaria, antes de mais nada, mudar sua tabela e adicionar uma chave primária (pode ser um campo `id` simples.

```
CREATE TABLE tmpPedidos(
  [id] integer identity(1,1),
  [Docentry] integer,
  [qty] integer,
  [onhand] integer,
  [conta] integer,
);
```

Depois faça um insert deixando os dados da coluna conta sem preencher:

```
INSERT INTO tmpPedidos([Docentry],[qty],[onhand])
VALUES
    (15335, 12,3993),
    (156581,4,3993),
    (156582,2,3993),
    (156583,5,3993);
```

Agora com estes dados preenchidos podemos criar uma variável `@conta` que irá atualizar os valores das colunas `onhand` e `conta`. Observe também que criamos uma variável `@etoque_inicial` para guardar o valor inicial do estoque (3993), pois este será alterado e precisamos volta-lo manualmente.

```
/*guarda o estoque inicial*/
declare @estoque_inicial int
set @estoque_inicial = (select onhand from tmpPedidos where id = 1)

/*Faz update na tabela corrigindo os dados da coluna conta*/
declare @conta int
update tmpPedidos set conta = @conta, @conta = (ISNULL(@conta,onhand)-qty),onhand = ISNULL(@conta,onhand)

/*Faz update da primeira linha voltando o valor do estoque inicial*/
update tmpPedidos set onhand = @estoque_inicial where id = 1
```

Você pode testar o exemplo acima [aqui](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/aa4ac3/2).

Obs: Acho importante frisar que o mais fácil seria você fazer esse controle de estoque em uma tabela separada, onde iria receber somente os lançamentos de entrada e saída de cada item do estoque, desta maneira o seu controle seria muito mais fácil.

Comment: Valeu Murilo! Vou testar tudo certinho e te retorno, só uma pergunta:  os updates eu faço dentro do cursor para poder ir substituindo os dados do onhand conforme os pedidos forem passando?

Comment: @DouglasSouza, na verdade você substituiria todo o seu cursor pelos updates que passei, você corrige o seu insert removendo o `(c.OnHand - b.Quantity)`, para que ele não preencha o campo `conta` e depois que você inseriu os dados na tabela `#tmpPedidos` você usa os updates que lhe informei. Os updates vão percorrer todas as linhas da tabela calculando o valor da coluna `conta` conforme solicitado. Como é uma tabela temporária ela não deve estar mantendo muitos dados, então não terá problema de performance.

Comment: Bom dia Murilo! vi que a conta funciona perfeitamente mas tenho 1 problema. o onhand e a conta estão se baseando em todo o estoque de todos os itens, no caso eu gostaria apenas de baixar o estoque de cada item. Por exemplo:
o item AR000001 tem 3993 de estoque, após a conta ficaria 3981
o item AR000002 tem 200 de estoque, se dentro do pedido onde o ar000001 foi vendido não existir o 02, o estoque do 02 permaneceria o mesmo, porém ao executar seu código todos os itens estão sendo alterados.

Answer (score 0):

Partilho um exemplo de criar temp table. De seguida partilho um exemplo de cursor...partilho um exemplo e ajustas ao teu caso.

**Create TEMP Table**

```
IF(OBJECT_ID('#ID_Table') IS NULL)
    BEGIN
        --IF NULL CREATE TEMP TABLE
        CREATE TABLE #ID_Table
        (
            [ID] INT
        );
    END
```

**Remove TEMP table**

```
--DROP TEMP TABLE IF EXISTS AFTER USAGE
IF(OBJECT_ID('#ID_Table') IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE #ID_Table
END
```

[Cursores Documentação oficial Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/declare-cursor-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

**Exemplo Cursor**

NOTA: O teu select para colocar em memória os dados terá de ser da TEMP table, este exemplo é de uma tabela normal.

[Fonte](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1599/sql-server-cursor-example/)

```
DECLARE @name VARCHAR(50) -- database name 
DECLARE @path VARCHAR(256) -- path for backup files 
DECLARE @fileName VARCHAR(256) -- filename for backup 
DECLARE @fileDate VARCHAR(20) -- used for file name 

SET @path = 'C:\Backup\' 

SELECT @fileDate = CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),GETDATE(),112) 

DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR 
SELECT name 
FROM MASTER.dbo.sysdatabases 
WHERE name NOT IN ('master','model','msdb','tempdb') 

OPEN db_cursor  
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @name  

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN  
      SET @fileName = @path + @name + '_' + @fileDate + '.BAK' 
      BACKUP DATABASE @name TO DISK = @fileName 

      FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @name 
END 

CLOSE db_cursor  
DEALLOCATE db_cursor
```

Comment: Grato Ernesto! Muito obrigado pelas dicas.