# Must declare the scalar variable "@doc"

Tags: sql, sql-server

Pesquisei bastante sobre esse erro mas nada me pareceu semelhante ao que está me ocorrendo, criei um cursor e após realizar o fetch next me retorna o erro do título, alguém poderia ajudar?

```css
declare @doc int
,@qnt int
,@estoqueantigo int
,@onhandatt int
,@icode varchar(20)
declare crs cursor
for
select * from #tmpPedidos order by itemcode
open crs
fetch next from crs into @doc,@qnt,@estoqueantigo,@onhandatt,@icode;
      insert into #tmp2(Docentry,qty,onhand,itemcode) values (@doc,@qnt,@onhandatt,@icode)
      update #tmpPedidos set Docentry=Docentry,qty=qty,onhand=@onhandatt,conta=@onhandatt-qty,itemcode=itemcode where itemcode = @icode
close crs
deallocate crs
```

aqui existem 2 tabelas temporárias, uma para realizar a função e outra para receber os resultados, atualmente só consigo mostrar o primeiro resultado, vou mostrar o código das partes anteriores.

```html
create table #tmpPedidos(
Docentry int
,qty int
,onhand int
,conta int
,itemcode varchar(20)
)
--insere na tabela
insert into #tmpPedidos(Docentry,qty,onhand,conta,itemcode)
(select a.docentry,b.Quantity,c.OnHand,(c.OnHand - b.Quantity),b.ItemCode
from ORDR a 
inner join RDR1 b on a.DocEntry = b.DocEntry
inner join OITW c on b.ItemCode = c.ItemCode
where
a.DocStatus = 'o' and a.CANCELED = 'n' and c.whscode = 
CASE when BPLId = 4 then '301' 
ELSE
'401'
END)

create table #tmp2 (
Docentry int
,qty int
,onhand int
,itemcode varchar(20)
)
```

observem que no primeiro trecho de código que coloquei existe a declaração dos valores, o cursor ainda está incompleto e estou utilizando ele "na mão" selecionando e clicando no fetch next para testar, assim descobri que só a primeira linha é inserida na tabela #tmp2.

Desde já agradeço!

Comment: Olá Douglas, melhora a tua questão. Sabes que quando estamos a ajudar em dúvidas que colocam na plataforma tentamos ser o mais assertivos possível nas respostas, contudo é importante **saber** perguntar. A minha principal dúvida é, porque precisas de duas tabelas temporárias? O que fazes com os valores depois de insert numa e update noutra, sendo tabelas temporárias, não faz sentido. Explica melhor e posso ajudar-te.

Comment: Bem me parecia que já tinha visto isto, já tinha [partilhado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/411094/uso-de-cursor-para-atualiza%c3%a7%c3%a3o-de-estoque-item-a-item/411144?noredirect=1#comment803053_411144) como criar um cursor, temp table, etc.  Uma nota, identa a tua script de forma a ficar mais elegível ou interpretável ao "olho humano".

Comment: Outra coisa, testei correr a tua script, sem o insert e não dá qualquer erro. Será que aconteceu de correres a script ao utilizares a abordagem de seleccionar tudo e não seleccionaste a primeira linha onde defines o declare @doc int?

Comment: Ernesto, como é minha primeira vez usando cursor e temp table não soube organizar muito bem os dados por isso deixei um pouco confuso, mas vou melhorar. Atualmente é o insert que deveria atualizar para eu obter o resultado necessário, sem ele a query roda normalmente mas preciso inserir os dados com a conta feita para trazer a informação que necessito.

Comment: Consegui aqui senhores.